# Find three subspace$ W_{1} ,W_{2}, W_{3}$ such that for a given subspace U, $F^{5} = U\oplus W_{1}\oplus W_{2} \oplus W_{3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum

$$U=\{(x,y,x+y,x-y,2x) \in{F^{5}} : x,y\in{F}\}$$ then find $W_{1},W_{2}$ and $W_{3}$, none of which equals $\{0\}$ such that $$F^{5} = U \oplus W_{1}\oplus W_{2}\oplus W_{3}$$
What I have done is $(a,b,c,d,e) \in{F^{5}}$ Then $$(a,b,c,d,e)=(a,b,a+b,a-b,2a)+(a,b,c-a-b,d-a+b,e-2a)+(-a,b,0, 0,0)+(0,-2b,0,0,0)$$ Hence $$W_{1}=(a,b,c-a-b,d-a+b,e-2a)$$ $$W_{2}=(-a,b,0,0,0)$$ $$W_{3}=(0,-2b,0,0,0)$$ 
I don't have answer. I don't know what I have done is correct or not. Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 1):

You already have $(1,0,1,1,2)$ and $(0,1,1,-1,0)$ as linearly independent members of $U$.

You need to find three more (linearly independent) basis vectors.

Any set of linearly independent vectors can be put into row echelon form in a matrix. Let's assume we have the three additional vectors:

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccccc} 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & a & b & c \\
0 & 0 & 0 & d & e \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & f \end{array}\right)$$

These five row-vectors are linearly independent if, and only if, the determinant of the five-by-five matrix is non-zero: i.e. $adf \neq 0$. Personally, I would just choose

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccccc} 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right)$$

meaning that $W_1 = \operatorname{span}(0,0,1,0,0)$, $W_2 = \operatorname{span}(0,0,0,1,0)$ and $W_3 = \operatorname{span}(0,0,0,0,1)$.

Comment: Thank you:) I didn't think like this

Comment: @SmritiTiwari That's the whole idea of education. I didn't think like this until someone showed me that I could think like this. Now you know, and now you can apply this. Please remember to upvote answers you find useful, and also to choose your favourite answer using the tick.